# Add Data To New Row Of DataGrid

Tags: c#, datatable, webforms

I am attempting to add in a row with only a header in it to a data table.
I want my data in the data table to be set-up like this.

> Row 1 ---- Round Data
>       Row 2 ---- data from text boxes

What I am currently getting is

> Row 1 ---- Round Data --- data from textboxes

How should I ammend my code so that it lines the data up with a new row?

```
DataRow dr = null;
dtResult.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mainevent", typeof(string)));
dtResult.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("secondevent", typeof(string)));

dtResult.Columns["mainevent"].Expression = "'Round Data'";
dr = dt.Result.NewRow();

foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdOther.Rows)
{
    dr = dtResult.NewRow();
    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)gr.Cells[1].FindControl("txtmainevent");
    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)gr.Cells[2].FindControl("txtse");

    dr["mainevent"] = box1.Text;
    dr["secondevent"] = box2.Text;

    dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new row.

```
        DataRow dr = null;
        dtResult.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mainevent",typeof(string)));

        dtResult.Columns["mainevent"].Expression = "'Round Data'";
        dr = dt.Result.NewRow();
        DataRow dr2 = dt.Result.NewRow();

        foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdOther.Rows)
        {


            dr = dtResult.NewRow();
            dr2 = dtResult.NewRow();

            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)gr.Cells[1].FindControl("txtmainevent");
            TextBox box2 = (TextBox)gr.Cells[2].FindControl("txtse");

            dr["mainevent"] = box1.Text;
            dr2["mainevent"] = box2.Text;

            dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);dtResult.Rows.Add(dr2);
        }
```